# What is the "right" way to set up code pipeline to deploy different branches to different Elastic Beanstalk environments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, continuous-integration, aws-codepipeline

This is a basic question:
I have a basic codepipeline pipeline set up like the following:

1. Source is github branch (master)
2. Build with AWS Codebuild
3. Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk -> deploys to appname-prod environment

That all makes sense and is straightforward.

Now I want to do the same thing for staging: have a staging branch, and when it's commited to, Codebuild builds it, and it's deployed to the appname-staging environment.

What's the right way to do this?

Should I just have two different pipelines (one for prod and one for staging)?

Or is there a good way to have both of those behaviors (and potentially a third) within the same pipeline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a pipeline per branch from my experience. It may be the case that the pipeline structure for each environment is different or the same.

If you opt to do a CI/CD setup, then the non-production pipeline will include stages for testing etc and assuming each stage passes, the deployment will be then automatic to the non-prod elasticbeanstalk environment.

For the production environment, you may wish to include a manual approval stage thus having a continuous delivery pipeline. Or if it is ok to do automatic deployments you could use the pipeline format for non-prod.

A nice trick if you wish to use a pipeline you've created manually over and over again. Is to extract a cloudformation template of it via the cli.

```
aws codepipeline getpipeline --name <name>
```

This gives you a cloudformation template for the codepipeline resource. You will need to edit a bit, but if it references a repo and branch, you can adjust that. You can also parameterise it so that you can create many pipelines easily which have a similar structure.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with this issue for a while. CodePipeline only allows sources on the first step, which means you can't do your source-build-deploy steps for dev and then repeat for higher environments within the same pipeline.